# simple OpenGL/GLUT program not compiling on Windows

Tags: opengl, glut

I am trying to compile a simple application using GLUT on Windows. On Linux, it compiled with no errors. On Windows, I tried Visual C++ Express 2010 and CodeBlocks and got same errors on both. I added libraries, header files and dll files to appropriate directories. I added the libraries to the linker's settings. Do you know what the problem is?

Errors:

```
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp||In function 'void DrawGLScene()':|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|259|error: 'glUseProgramObjectARB' was not     declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|262|error: 'glUniform1ui' was not declared   in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|263|error: 'glVertexAttribPointerARB' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|270|error: expected initializer before '*' token|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|284|error: expected initializer before '*' token|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp||In function 'void log(int)':|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|299|error: 'GL_OBJECT_INFO_LOG_LENGTH_ARB' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|300|error: 'glGetObjectParameterivARB' was not  declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|303|error: 'glGetInfoLogARB' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp||In function 'unsigned int load_shader()':|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|310|error: 'glCreateProgramObjectARB' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|311|error: 'GL_VERTEX_SHADER_ARB' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|311|error: 'glCreateShaderObjectARB' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|312|error: 'GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_ARB' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|313|error: 'V_SHADER' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|313|error: 'glShaderSourceARB' was not   declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|314|error: 'F_SHADER' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|315|error: 'glCompileShaderARB' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|319|error: 'glAttachObjectARB' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|321|error: 'glLinkProgramARB' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|322|error: 'glUseProgramObjectARB' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|323|error: 'glGetUniformLocationARB' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|325|error: 'glGetAttribLocation' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|330|error: 'glUniformMatrix4fv' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|332|error: 'glUseProgram' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|333|error: 'glEnableVertexAttribArray' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|335|error: 'glDeleteObjectARB' was not declared in this scope|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp||In function 'int main(int, char**)':|
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|355|error: 'glDeleteObjectARB' was not declared     in this scope|
||=== Build finished: 26 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

The code if needed:

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES 1
#define GL3_PROTOTYPES 1
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int window;
int shader;

unsigned char texture[]= {0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
                      0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
                      0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
                      0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
                      0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
                      0xFF,0x00,0x00,0xFF,
                      0xFF,0x00,0x00,0xFF,
                      0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
                      0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
                      0xFF,0x00,0x00,0xFF,
                      0xFF,0x00,0x00,0xFF,
                      0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
                      0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
                      0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
                      0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
                      0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF};
static const float Z=-1.0;

static const float vertices[]={ -0.5, -0.5, Z,
               0.5, -0.5, Z,
               0.5,  0.5, Z,
              -0.5,  0.5, Z };

static const float texcoord[]={ 0.0, 0.0,
               1.0, 0.0,
               1.0, 1.0,
               0.0, 1.0 };

static const char indices[]={ 0,1,2,3 };

unsigned int texcnt;
unsigned int projection_matrix_loc;
unsigned int modelview_matrix_loc;
unsigned int vertex_loc;
unsigned int tex_coordinates_loc;
unsigned int tex_loc;

void InitGL(int Width, int Height) // Funkcja wolana po utworzeniu okna
{
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // kolor tla czarny
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_POLYGON);
glClearDepth(1.0);                    // Enables Clearing Of The Depth Buffer
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);              // Enables Depth Testing
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glGenTextures(1,&texcnt);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texcnt);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,4,4,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

void ReSizeGLScene(int Width, int Height)
{
if (Height==0) Height=1;
glViewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void DrawGLScene()
{
glutSetWindow(window); // Aktywne okno
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glUseProgramObjectARB(shader);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texcnt);
glUniform1ui(tex_loc,0); // Jednostka teksturuj¹ca 0
glVertexAttribPointerARB(vertex_loc,3,GL_FLOAT,0,0,vertices);
glVertexAttribPointerARB(tex_coordinates_loc,2,GL_FLOAT,0,0,texcoord);
glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,indices);
glUseProgramObjectARB(0);
glutSwapBuffers();
}

const GLcharARB* V_SHADER[] = { //call per vertex
"uniform mat4 projection_matrix;"
"uniform mat4 modelview_matrix;"
"attribute vec3 vertex;"
"attribute vec2 tex_coordinates;"
"varying vec2 tex_coord;"
"void main()"
"{"
"tex_coord = tex_coordinates;"
"gl_Position = projection_matrix*modelview_matrix*vec4(vertex,1.0);"
"}"
};


const GLcharARB* F_SHADER[] = { //call per pixel
"varying vec2 tex_coord;"
"uniform sampler2D tex;"
"void main()"
"{"
"vec4 color = texture2D(tex,tex_coord);"
"gl_FragColor = color;"
"}"
};


void log(int shader) {
char* info_log;
int info_log_len=0;
int chars_written=0;
glGetObjectParameterivARB(shader,GL_OBJECT_INFO_LOG_LENGTH_ARB,
        &info_log_len);
if (info_log_len>0) {
    info_log= new char[info_log_len];
    glGetInfoLogARB(shader,info_log_len,&chars_written,info_log);
    std::cout << info_log;
    delete [] info_log;
  }
}

unsigned int load_shader() {
unsigned int p = glCreateProgramObjectARB();
unsigned int v = glCreateShaderObjectARB(GL_VERTEX_SHADER_ARB);
unsigned int f = glCreateShaderObjectARB(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_ARB);
glShaderSourceARB(v, 1, V_SHADER,0);
glShaderSourceARB(f, 1, F_SHADER,0);
glCompileShaderARB(v);
log(v);
glCompileShaderARB(f);
log(f);
glAttachObjectARB(p,v);
glAttachObjectARB(p,f);
glLinkProgramARB(p);
glUseProgramObjectARB(p);
modelview_matrix_loc = glGetUniformLocationARB(p,"modelview_matrix");
projection_matrix_loc = glGetUniformLocationARB(p,"projection_matrix");
tex_coordinates_loc = glGetAttribLocation(p,"tex_coordinates");
vertex_loc = glGetAttribLocation(p,"vertex");
tex_loc = glGetUniformLocationARB(p,"tex");
   const float identity[16] =
    {1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1}; // mat jednostkowa nic nie robi
glUniformMatrix4fv(projection_matrix_loc,1,GL_FALSE,identity);
glUniformMatrix4fv(modelview_matrix_loc,1,GL_FALSE,identity);
glUseProgram(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertex_loc);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(tex_coordinates_loc);
glDeleteObjectARB(v);
glDeleteObjectARB(f);
return p;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
window = glutCreateWindow("Bitmapka");
glutDisplayFunc(&DrawGLScene);
//glutFullScreen();
glutIdleFunc(&DrawGLScene);
glutReshapeFunc(&ReSizeGLScene);
shader = load_shader();
InitGL(640, 480);
glutMainLoop();
glDeleteObjectARB(shader);
glutDestroyWindow(window);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows the OpenGL interface DLL exposes only the OpenGL-1.1 API, nothing more. So to use newer functions, you must load them at runtime through the extension mechanism. Go to http://glew.sourceforge.net read the documentation, install it, use it.

Seriously, this is a FAQ asked about every 2nd day on StackOverflow.

---

BTW: On Linux the official OpenGL-ABI for libGL.so only defines OpenGL-1.2, so technically you'd have to use the extension mechanism on Linux as well. However most libGL.so to export the newer symbols just like that, so what you did works for this very reason.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it still does not work. Probably, I am doing something wrong, but I tried to stick to guide on the glew website you gave me. Now I am getting errors like these:
     D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|261|undefined reference to `__glewUseProgramObjectARB'|
     D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\main.cpp|264|undefined    reference to`__glewUniform1ui'|

I linked the libraries, added headers, dll...